# How to call a web method which is in Root Page in ASP.NET using AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

A function needs to be called from every page, this function is a Web Method. Its in the Roor.Master Page now how can it be called from all pages using AJAX. Since there are many pages creating same function or a function which calls this function in turn is hectic.

Comment: Have you considered exposing the functionality as an WebAPI endpoint or creating a BasePage class that inherits from `Page`, that would contain that method? Every page inheriting from that Page would contain that method.

Comment: @Marco , yes this is an option but i was trying to find the shortest solution if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you have common functionality, that is shared between most or all of your WebForms, you can always create a Base page class, which inherits from `Page`. All other pages, that are derived from your base class, would then contain that method:

```
public class MyBasePage : Page
{
   [WebMethod]
   public static void DoStuff()
   {
       //Do your work here
   }
}
```

No, whenever you need that method, you can just inherit your aspx webform from `MyBasePage` instead of `Page`:

```
public partial class Foo : MyBasePage
{
   /*...*/
}
```

Since you can also use WebApi, MVC and WebForms side by side in the same project, exposing this functionality through a simple ApiController could be feasible as well, if you do not need to access webforms specific elements, like variables that are defined your Base page oder master page.

Answer (score 0):

There is no physical existance of pagemethod after the page is rendered. So, jquery ajax call is not possible to a page method in master page. But following code looks impressive to me.

http://weblogs.asp.net/yonggangmeng/archive/2008/11/13/how-to-invoke-pagemethods-in-masterpage.aspx